# Need to grab the HTML content and Id using php and then echo it?

Tags: php, html, echo, innerhtml

The following is an example of my HTML page followed by a piece of the corresponding PHP page that is handling the form. I need to get the HTML content (ie the string) from the id and echo it using PHP. The  hold the results of some equations. I want the PHP to handle the results and echo them into a well organized table.

HTML

```
<span id="a" name="a"></span>
<span id="b" name="b"></span>
```

When a function runs it inserts the answers into the id's a and b. Now I want to echo these answers using PHP when the form is submitted.

Comment: I don't see any PHP here...

Comment: Q: Are you familiar with 1) How PHP interacts with HTML on the server before it's sent to the client, 2) How Javascript interacts with HTML on the client (and how Ajax can communicate back with the server), and 3) How PHP interacts with the HTTP form data returned by the client?  If so, exactly what part (1, 2 or 3) are you asking about?  It sounds like you just want a simple form, and have PHP process it (3).  Here's a good tutorial: [PHP Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Yes, and I see no form either. Or anything else that explains in code what should be done. And what has been tried. And what is the current result and how it differs from the expected result.

Comment: Yes, I know how it all works, I tried to only give the minimum needed to possibly answer the question I have a form that is filled out by the user, a script then works with the user inputs to create a list of prices and items, these prices and items are displayed at the bottom of the page in a table, I used <span> tags with id's to tell Javascript where to write the answers using document.getElementById.innerHTML, under this table There is a button to submit the form. I want to display these same results in a well organized table that can be printed.

Comment: This isn't about you telling us the minimum info so that somebody can come up with an answer that is only helping you, but nobody else. This about giving all relevant info firsthand, and then helping finding a solution by eventually adding more info as is being requested.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make a form, if you don't know how to then take a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Then learn the post method to post the data that you want to echo, currently you have no form so it's not going to work. Or maybe you do but are not showing us, if that is the case please put all you code on.